# How can I ctrl-alt-f# to get to a TTY in a QEMU session?

Tags: qemu

I'm doing an install via testdrive using QEMU/KVM and I would like to check the log files during the installation, however I can't figure out a way to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and other F keys to the virtualized window (It instead goes to the TTY on the host machine).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>4</kbd> send me to some kind of QEMU consoles (the installer is on one, then there are qemu consoles and one serial and one parallel, so I think I'm getting close.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`sendkey` can be used to send keys to the virtual system that your host intercepts at low level - such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F*</kbd>.

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to switch to the QEMU console.
2. Type `sendkey ctrl-alt-f1` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to switch back to the virtual system, which should now by at TTY1.

Once at a virtual terminal, you should be able to use the `chvt` command, e.g. `sudo chvt 7` to go back to your X session.

Comment: +1, it works if you don't set `-monitor stdio` (as do aqemu GUI by default)

Comment: When I do Ctrl-Alt-2 to switch to the QEMU console, I see grey-on-blue text saying "parallel0 console". None of my further keypresses seem to do anything; or if they do, they don't echo. Certainly finishing with a newline/enter has no effect at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work when QEMU is running under Gnome Boxes.

Answer (score 22):

You can change tty in the guest os running on qemu with `ALT` + left or right arrows on the keypad.

Comment: Works on QEMU 2 Ubuntu 14.04 and https://github.com/cirosantilli/runlinux The lack of upvotes for this best answer must imply it is a new feature :-)

Comment: Well I am using it for quite some time now but I can't remember where/when I first read about it :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me on qemu 2.8.1 on Debian.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using sticky keys: Press the first key three times to "**stick**" it to the "**virtualized window**" followed by the other keys e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

This should send the command to the virtual machine instead of the host machine "**hijacking**" it.

Comment: Could not get his working in QEMU 2 Ubuntu 14.04. Can you link to the docs?

Comment: Doesn't work for me on qemu 2.8.1 on Debian.